# parse json when value of one json becomes key of another json in java

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

I have two jsons like these

```
{
   "clientId":"patientId",
   "vendorId":"businessKey"
}


{
   "patientId":"1234",
   "businessKey":"abcd"
}
```

I have java POJOs created like these

```
public class Patient{

private String patientId;
private String businessKey;

public String getPatientId() {
    return patientId;
}

public void setPatientId(String patientId) {
    this.patientId = patientId;
}

public String getBusinessKey() {
    return businessKey;
}

public void setBusinessKey(String businessKey) {
    this.businessKey = businessKey;
}
}


public class Client {

     private String clientId;
     private String vendorId;

     public String getClientId() {
       return clientId;
     }

     public void setClientId(String clientId) {
      this.clientId = clientId;
     }

      public String getVendorId() {
        return vendorId;
      }

      public void setVendorId(String vendorId) {
        this.vendorId = vendorId;
      }

}
```

I am using Jackson's ObjectMapper to parse the JSON. What I want to achieve is first read the first JSON, get the value from that and then read the actual value from the second JSON.
Ex: I read the first JSON to getClientId - "patientId"
Then in the second JSON I should read getPatientId - 1234.

How do I achieve this programmatically. I dont want to clutter my code by adding lot many if else blocks. Is there any library that I could use?

Comment: check this link: http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-jackson-Data-Binding.jsp